# MS Access 2007 SQL Syntax Error in Join expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join four tables and I am getting the error 'Syntax error in Join Expression'

Please find below the query I am presently trying to write

```
SELECT a.*,
switch(a.[Start Date] between b.[SEASON1START] and b.[SEASON1END],b.[LRA_S1_RT1_SGL],
a.[Start Date] between c.[SEASON1START] and c.[SEASON1END],c.[LRA_S1_RT1_SGL],
a.[Start Date] between d.[SEASON1START] and d.[SEASON1END],d.[LRA_S1_RT1_SGL]) as [Negotiated Rate Local],
switch(a.[Start Date] between b.[SEASON1START] and b.[SEASON1END],
b.[RATE_CURR],a.[Start Date] between c.[SEASON1START] and c.[SEASON1END],c.[RATE_CURR],
a.[Start Date] between d.[SEASON1START] and d.[SEASON1END],d.[RATE_CURR]) as [Negotiated Currency]
FROM ((([Q1001 - Split Transactions] a 
left join [2014 Negotiated Rate] b on (a.[RX_ID] = b.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date] = 2014))
left join [2015 Negotiated Rate] c on (a.[RX_ID] = c.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date] = 2015)) 
left join [2016 Negotiated Rate] d on (a.[RX_ID] = d.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date] = 2016)) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access does not permit constants in the `on` clause.  The solution?  Switch to a better database.  Oh wait.  That isn't always an option.  So, subqueries to the rescue:

```
FROM ((([Q1001 - Split Transactions] a left join
        (SELECT b.*, 2014 as yyyy FROM [2014 Negotiated Rate] as b
        ) as b
        on a.[RX_ID] = b.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date]) = b.yyyy
       ) left join
       (SELECT c.*, 2015 as yyyy FROM [2015 Negotiated Rate] as c
       ) as c
       on a.[RX_ID] = c.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date]) = c.yyyy
      ) left join
      (SELECT d.*, 2016 as yyyy FROM [2016 Negotiated Rate] as d
      ) as d
      on a.[RX_ID] = d.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date]) = d.yyyy
     )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am still getting the same error even after replacing the code as per your suggestion.

Comment: "Switch to a better database" too honest :)

Comment: @AyanMukherje . . . I thought a subquery would do it.  Perhaps a view is needed.

Comment: Well it worked after I made a couple of edits and checked the brackets. Thanks for your help Gordon :). I am new to this community and I've a couple of questions, any way we can connect and discuss them?

Answer (score 1):

Your original query should work. In MS Access, you can have expressions in `ON` clauses like `WHERE` clauses (though intricate expressions will not be viewable in *Design View* only in *SQL View*).

Specifically, you are not wrapping the `YEAR()` function properly. Consider the following adjustment:

```
FROM ((([Q1001 - Split Transactions] a 
left join [2014 Negotiated Rate] b 
      on (a.[RX_ID] = b.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date]) = 2014))
left join [2015 Negotiated Rate] c 
      on (a.[RX_ID] = c.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date]) = 2015)) 
left join [2016 Negotiated Rate] d 
      on (a.[RX_ID] = d.[PROPCODE] And YEAR(a.[Start Date]) = 2016));
```